# chown on files after php/apache upgrade

Tags: php, apache, chmod, chown

Right now i'm using php 5.4.37 and Apache 2.2.29

I just upgrade from php 5.4.32 with easyApache on WHM

Before the upgrade all files created with 'fopen' php scripts had the following user:group 504:516

Now the files created with 'fopen' php scripts are 99:99

I can't do now any 'fopen', 'unlink', etc... on all files with 504:516 !!!

**I missed something ???**

I known i can change with 'chown' my files, but i would like to be able to use my script with 'fopen' or 'unlink' on files with 504:516 like i did before ;))

Thanks for your help...

**NOTE**
Just a screen copy about specific option i choose to compile
[image]

**UPDATED**

**I changed PHP handler from DSO to suPHP and now it's fine ;))**

Thx

Comment: so look in /etc/password for the usernames for id = 99 and id=504, and change apache to run as that id.

Comment: Did you compile with suPHP? You probably should this way different accounts can't edit each others files.

Comment: @Mark : I have multi sites on this server ! Is this is a good solution ?

Comment: verify the user who launch Apache server

Comment: @cmorrissey : Where can i check if i compiled with suPHP. I think this is the problem !

Comment: @Halayem : with echo exec('whoami') i get 'nobody' (99)

Comment: Ok, so try to start your Apache with the credentials of user 504

Comment: @Halayem : Sorry this is Chinese language for me (lol). Can you explain (thx)

Comment: stop apache service, do a substitute user to 504 using `su` command and then start Apache service and try

Comment: @Halayem : Not sure I will be able to do that but I will try... Thx